# Input content vanishes after few seconds

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I've created an simple input form. When the button is clicked the content gets prepended to "ul". That works fine, however almost immediately the newly created li vanishes.

I've created a jsfiddle and after few seconds an error appears.
http://jsfiddle.net/pcgwqbbx/

jQuery code

```
$(".input").keyup(function() {
    var characters = $(this).val().length;
    $(".chars").text(characters).append(" Zeichen eingegeben");
    if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
        $(".submit").addClass("disabled").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $(".submit").removeClass("disabled").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
    var post = $(".input").val();
    $("<li>").text(post).prependTo("ul");
});
$(".submit").addClass("disabled").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: The only error I see is when the form submits. That's expected, no?

Comment: nope, actually not. what is wrong with my submit part?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pcgwqbbx/1/ like this changed `type=submit` to `type=button`

Comment: that was easy... thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/pcgwqbbx/1/

Just change the input type `submit` to `button`

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Eintragen" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" name="submit" class="submit" value="Eintragen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `return false;` while your input `type="submit"`

```
var main = function () {

    $(".input").keyup(function() {
        var characters = $(this).val().length;
        $(".chars").text(characters).append(" Zeichen eingegeben");
        if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
            $(".submit").addClass("disabled").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $(".submit").removeClass("disabled").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var post = $(".input").val();
        $("<li>").text(post).prependTo("ul");
        return false;
    });
    $(".submit").addClass("disabled").attr("disabled", "disabled");
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pcgwqbbx/2/)